# Return a value given its position

Tags: r

I am trying to create a vector with the values from an ordered number-set given its position. The values for the respective position is in a single column vector. I would therefore like the result to be in a vector. Something like this:

```
x.numbers <- c(100,120,140,160,180,200) #The ordered numbers

pos<-c(1,1,3,2,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,3,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1)
position<-cbind(pos) #Vector with respective position
```

The answer I am looking for should return the vector:

```
 Value
[1,]   100
[2,]   100
[3,]   140
[4,]   120
[5,]   100
[6,]   120
[7,]   120
[8,]   160
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using a loop? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the sounds of it you can just use `x.numbers[pos]`, or perhaps you're looking for something like:

```
> cbind(pos, value = x.numbers[pos])
      pos value
 [1,]   1   100
 [2,]   1   100
 [3,]   3   140
 [4,]   2   120
 [5,]   1   100
 [6,]   2   120
 [7,]   2   120
 [8,]   4   160
 [9,]   4   160
[10,]   4   160
[11,]   1   100
[12,]   3   140
[13,]   2   120
[14,]   3   140
[15,]   3   140
[16,]   3   140
[17,]   1   100
[18,]   1   100
[19,]   1   100
[20,]   1   100
```

Comment: Thanks Ananda. I was trying `apply()` but I realized it wouldn't work. Thanks a million once again.

Comment: @user2507608, just FYI, `apply()` and Co. generally just hide a loop--they aren't "loopless" solutions. Also, loops in R are fine, as long as they are well-written.

Comment: I try to use loops when I am sure there isn't a simpler command. I figured there should be a simpler way to do what I wanted, but all my reading, research and brain-storming didn't work. I have over 14000 rows of data, and running some scripts with loops takes over 10 mins, hence me trying to avoid them wherever possible. But thanks again.  Kurt

Comment: @user2507608, check to see that you're not unnecessarily growing objects in your loop. Pre-allocation makes loops much more efficient. 10 minutes for 14k rows seems like *a very long time* though.